# Como usar um COUNT com condição?

Tags: sql, sql-select, group-by

Tenho uma tabela `quarto`, queria retornar a quantidade de quartos que tem em cada andar (o quarto possui um atributo `andar`), mas não sei como fazer com que ele retorne de todos os andares

```sql
SELECT andar, COUNT(* WHERE andar = andar????? ) AS quantidade
```

Queria um retorno tipo

```
andar  quantidade
1      5
2      10
3      6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você quer que a função `COUNT()` seja agregadora, quer contar todos os elementos encontrados dentro de um grupo de dados, esse grupo é definido pelo atributo `andar`, então use a cláusula `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT andar, COUNT(*) AS quantidade FROM andares GROUP BY andar
```

Veja [funcionando no **SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/80069/1). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CountGroupBy.sql).

Comment: Isso! Valeu! Estou aprendendo e fiquei na dúvida